# Emberjs - Controller always gets default value from 'needs' controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a situation where I have an application controller that 'needs' to access a property from another controller, like this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['sort'],

    actions: {
        appClicked: function () {
            console.log('controllers.sort.isMenuExpanded');
        }
    }
});

App.SortController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isMenuExpanded: false,

    actions: {
        menuClicked: function () {
            this.toggleProperty('isMenuExpanded');
        }
    }
})
```

As expected, the ApplicationController's appClicked function correctly logs 'false' the first time it is run. However, it continues logging false (the default value set in the SortController) even after the isMenuExpanded property has been changed to 'true' by the SortController.

This may have something to do with the way JavaScript passes values. I think objects are passed by reference, and sure enough, if I change the isMenuExpanded property to:

```
isMenuExpanded: { expanded: false }
```

and change the toggle to:

```
this.toggleProperty('isMenuExpanded.expanded');
```

the action in the ApplicationController correctly prints the isMenuExpanded.expanded value to the console every time it's updated.

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting it as a computed property.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['sort'],
    isMenuExpanded: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.sort.isMenuExpanded'),

    actions: {
        appClicked: function () {
            console.log(this.get('isMenuExpanded'));
        }
    }
});

App.SortController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isMenuExpanded: false,

    actions: {
        menuClicked: function () {
            this.toggleProperty('isMenuExpanded');
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @benihana21 if you can put your code in a jsbin then we can debug further

Comment: When I try it in a jsbin, it works! I'm using a pre-Ember 1.11 release, so they probably has something to do with it. Here's the jsbin in case anyone would like to see the example. http://jsbin.com/vorokarega/8/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @benihana21 yep sure works! example with the computed alias http://jsbin.com/wugoteqobi/1/edit